# How to use Apache spark to implement GraphSAGE?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graphsage

I want to use scala and spark to implement Graph algorithm GraphSAGE, then how to do it? Is there any source code?

I want to get the code for my question

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and show your work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven´t implemented yet this graph algorithms on top of Spark, the only available implementation, as far as I know, for using deep learning for graph analysis is [this](https://github.com/emartinezs44/SparkGCN). It is a spectral graph convolution for semi-supervised learning, and it is a transductive algorithm. It can be used for node classification. I have plans to include more algorithms in the future like GraphSAGE.

Comment: Thank you very much, I would be appreciate if you can implement it as soon as possible